# Calculate how long supply will last weighted on more recent trends

Tags: statistics

Suppose there’s a known quantity of some discrete items and timestamps of them consumed until now. How do I calculate the most accurate estimate on how long the supply will last putting more weight on more recent rates of consumption?

Comment: To start off with, think of how you would calculate average consumption per day; then if you have an initial supply, you can take away from the initial supply each day.

Comment: How to account for recent trends of consumption is what I’m after here